# Speech bubble personalized

Tags: html, css, text, styles

hi everyone i am not good at front but i need to make a text bubble like this:
speechBubble [image]

my best attempt was this but I need to lower the diamond in half to make it look acceptable: myspeechBubble  [image]

if anyone knows how to do it in css I would really appreciate it, i need to place 3 different bubbles with one pointer in the middle, left and right

Comment: Please add the code snippets you tried with nd problem you faced

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below as your starting point and adjust the positions according to your needs.
Make use of psuedo selectors to achieve the same. ( there may be limitations on the styling properties)

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.box.arrow-top {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.box.arrow-top:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: -15px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid black;
}

.box.arrow-right:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 15px solid black;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}

.box.arrow-bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.box.arrow-left:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box arrow-top">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the top.
</div>

<div class="box arrow-right">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow on the right.
</div>

<div class="box arrow-bottom">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow at the bottom.
</div>

<div class="box arrow-left">
  This is a box with some content and an arrow on the left.
</div>
```